How to display 2 times an address field in form view Odoo 16
In the form view in Odoo 16, I have 2 times the same field, one to display only the name of the partner, and in another, I have the name and address.
In both cases, it displays the name and address.
It seems that I can't have 2 types of display for the same field?

xml
<group>
    <group>
        <field name="partner_shipping_id" />
    </group>
    <group>
        <field name="partner_shipping_id" context="{'show_address': 1}" options="{'always_reload': True, 'no_open':true}"  readonly="1"/>
    </group>
</group>

Any Idea ?

IIRC the fields will get the same "options" in the same view. You can call it Feature or Bug, but that's what i have experienced myself in some similar situations.

I'm afraid you're right CZoellner

What you can try to do is to create the field twice, but without having it in database twice:

partner_shipping_id2 = fields.Many2one(
    related="partner_shipping_id",
    readonly=True,
)

Now, simply define the new field in the form to ensure that it appears as intended. For example like:
<group>
    <group>
        <field name="partner_shipping_id2" />
    </group>
    <group>
        <field name="partner_shipping_id" context="{'show_address': 1}" options="{'always_reload': True, 'no_open':true}"  readonly="1"/>
    </group>
</group>


just try to take the customer name (partner_id.name) from the model and put it in the xml.
<group>
    <group>
            <field name="partner_id.name" string="Delivery Address" />
    </group>
    <group>
        <field name="partner_shipping_id" context="{'show_address': 1}" options="{'always_reload': True, 'no_open':true}"  readonly="1"/>
    </group>
</group>

by default, a snippet handles the shipping fields so tricky to customize the field but this way should do for you.

Thanks Masbha for your answer, but I want to display the partner_shipping_id field twice!
